# Good Linux editor (nedit replacement)?

Tags: linux, gui, text-editors

I'm looking for a nice lightweight programmers editor for Linux/UNIX.  I currently use nedit for normal text, and Eclipse when I want a new IDE.  Nedit has some UI quirks, and hasn't been updated in 5 years or so.
What nedit gives me and i need in the new editor:

- Nice Simple GUI
- Non-modal (I don't like vi)
- Lightweight (I don't like emacs, too much stuff to
  remember, remembering gets in the way
  of coding)
- regular expression
  search/replace.
- Autodetect newlines
  (pretty much any non-Windows editor
  does this)

Any suggestions?

Comment: 9 years later, and I just ran into this question seeking the same for myself. I found "nedit-ng", which does an awesome job at giving us nedit with smooth (antialiased) fonts (via qt5): https://github.com/eteran/nedit-ng

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you do not like the classical answers "vi(m)" and emacs, try "[cream](http://cream.sourceforge.net/)":

- it is essentially vim
- but with an newby-friendly config (which means: nedit like)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Geany](http://www.geany.org/)

> Geany is a text editor using the GTK2 toolkit with basic features of an integrated development environment. It was developed to provide a small and fast IDE, which has only a few dependencies from other packages. It supports many filetypes and has some nice features.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 1):

The editor from Midnight Commander is OK for me (mcedit) - of course, it's working in console.

Answer (score 0):

While I use gedit a lot, my favorite editor is still Notepad++ via wine.  Though there is a good discussion of both at stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72106/what-can-i-use-as-a-notepad-alternative-in-linux-ubuntu

Comment: Interesting, though doesn't using a text editor through an emulation environment create a lot of overhead?

Comment: @Rich Homolka: WINE is no emulator, it's an API wrapper ;-) and yes, wrapping adds some overhead

Answer (score 0):

[gedit](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/) is my lightweight editor of choice.

Comment: gedit doesn't have regular expression search-replace (well, I don't want to add extensions for it).  Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple curses style editor I prefer jove - a non-lisp emacs-like editor.  For GUI, gedit and kate are two good choices though I doubt they fit the "lightweight" category.